# how to split and insert CSV data into a new table in single statement?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, normalization

I have a table named "Documents" containing a column as below:

DocumentID

I have data in the format - @DocID =  1,2,3,4

How do I insert these documentID's in separate rows using a single query?

Comment: did any of these answer your question?

Answer (score 6):

You need a way to split and process the string in TSQL, there are many ways to do this.  This article covers the PROs and CONs of just about every method:

[Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005 and Beyond](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html)

You need to create a split function.  This is how a split function can be used:

```
SELECT
    *
    FROM YourTable                               y
    INNER JOIN dbo.yourSplitFunction(@Parameter) s ON y.ID=s.Value
```

[I prefer the number table approach to split a string in TSQL - Using a Table of Numbers](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html#tblnum) but there are numerous ways to split strings in SQL Server, see the previous link, which explains the PROs and CONs of each.

For the Numbers Table method to work, you need to do this one time table setup, which will create a table `Numbers` that contains rows from 1 to 10,000:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 IDENTITY(int,1,1) AS Number
    INTO Numbers
    FROM sys.objects s1
    CROSS JOIN sys.objects s2
ALTER TABLE Numbers ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Numbers PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (Number)
```

Once the Numbers table is set up, create this split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inline_split_me (@SplitOn char(1),@param varchar(7998)) RETURNS TABLE AS
   RETURN(SELECT substring(@SplitOn + @param + ',', Number + 1,
                    charindex(@SplitOn, @SplitOn + @param + @SplitOn, Number + 1) - Number - 1)
                 AS Value
          FROM   Numbers
          WHERE  Number <= len(@SplitOn + @param + @SplitOn) - 1
            AND  substring(@SplitOn + @param + @SplitOn, Number, 1) = @SplitOn)

GO
```

You can now easily split a CSV string into a table and join on it:

```
select * from dbo.inline_split_me(';','1;22;333;4444;;') where LEN(Value)>0
```

OUTPUT:

```
Value
----------------------
1
22
333
4444

(4 row(s) affected)
```

to make you new table use this:

```
--set up tables:
DECLARE @Documents table (DocumentID varchar(500), SomeValue varchar(5))
INSERT @Documents VALUES ('1,2,3,4','AAA')
INSERT @Documents VALUES ('5,6'    ,'BBBB')

DECLARE @NewDocuments table (DocumentID int, SomeValue varchar(5))

--populate NewDocuments
INSERT @NewDocuments
    (DocumentID, SomeValue)
SELECT
    c.value,a.SomeValue
    FROM @Documents    a
        CROSS APPLY dbo.inline_split_me(',',a.DocumentID) c

 --show NewDocuments contents:
select * from @NewDocuments
```

OUTPUT:

```
DocumentID  SomeValue
----------- ---------
1           AAA
2           AAA
3           AAA
4           AAA
5           BBBB
6           BBBB

(6 row(s) affected)
```

if you don't want to create a Numbers tableand are running SQL Server 2005 and up, you can just use this split function (no Numbers table required):

```
CREATE FUNCTION inline_split_me (@SplitOn char(1),@String varchar(7998))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (WITH SplitSting AS
           (SELECT
                LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1) AS Part
                    ,RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)) AS Remainder
                WHERE @String IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)-1)
                    ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder))
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                Remainder,null
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)=0
           )
           SELECT Part FROM SplitSting
       )
GO
```

Answer (score 3):

+1 for KM's thorough explanation.  This will get the job done quickly but maybe not necessarily most efficiently (again see KM's response for all the options)

My quick response:

Install [SQL#](http://www.sqlsharp.com/download/) (it's free and very useful)

Then

```
INSERT INTO Documents (documentId)
SELECT SplitVal FROM SQL#.String_Split(@DocId, ',', 1)
```

Comment: no offense intended, but I would be very leery of installing something like this on a production SQL Server, who knows what payload might be hidden inside that. The code in your answer runs on a single variable's value and not on every row in a table. As a result, you'd need the `CROSS APPLY` like in my answer to run the function on all rows in the old table.

Comment: @KM in the example given the input was held within a variable @DocId.  Not sure if this was an oversight by OP but it does make sense that the input isn't in multiple rows

Comment: @KM, as the author of SQL# I can assure you and everyone else that there is nothing harmful "hidden" inside. In fact, I am not even sure why you would suggest such a thing.

Comment: @srutzky, **sorry, I have no knowledge of any issues with installing SQL#** however, these days you need to be careful of what you download and install on your PC, let alone a server. If you are just running SQL Server for school or a hobby you might not need to worry about what you install on your SQL Server.  However, you need to be careful when installing anything onto a production SQL Server at your job. I'm very leery of installing internet downloads on my database at work. I'm not picking on SQL#, I'm just very cautious when it comes to installing 3rd party software in my database.

Comment: @KM, I appreciate that you are cautious but I think it might be more than necessary in this circumstance as there are ways of mitigating the risk with 3rd party software: testing and research. Testing can show undesirable side-effects and research can show if others have had issues. In the specific case here, the security is set to SAFE so the only potential risk is performance and again, that can be tested for.