# How to run SQL Server stored procedure query for each value of a CSV

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I am having following stored procedure in my SQL Server 2008 R2 database

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_send_email] 
    @pStatus Int Out,
    @pEMailId Int Out,
    @pSenderUserName varchar(MAX),  
    @pReceivers VarChar(50),         **-- this column can have csv values**
    @pSub NVarChar(100),
    @pCon NVarchar(MAX),
    @pHasAttachments Bit
AS
BEGIN
   --SET NOCOUNT ON;

   Insert Into MessagingMessage
      (
       CreatedBy,
       [Subject],
       Body,
       HasAttachments
      )
     Values
     (    
      @pSenderUserName,
      @pSub,
      @pCon,
      @pHasAttachments
      )
    SET @pEMailId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()  

     Insert Into MessagingMessageReceipient
      (
       MessageId,
       ReceipientId,
       ReceipientType
      )
     Values
     (    
      @pEMailId,
      @pReceivers,
      1
      )
     SET @pStatus  = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 

END
```

In above code I want to run the first statement only one time but second insert statements in loop for each comma separated username.CSV value coming as a parameter is already validated by C# code so no need to validate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this link: [how to split and insert CSV data into a new table in single statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265316/how-to-split-and-insert-csv-data-into-a-new-table-in-single-statement), there is a function you can use to parse csv to to table and I have used it in the code below. Try the following

```
Insert Into MessagingMessageReceipient
  (
   MessageId,
   ReceipientId,
   ReceipientType
  )
  SELECT
   @pEMailId,
   csv.Part,   -- each @pReceiver
   1
  FROM 
     dbo.inline_split_me(',',@pReceivers) csv
```

And the function is copied below

```
CREATE FUNCTION inline_split_me (@SplitOn char(1),@String varchar(7998))
RETURNS TABLE AS
RETURN (WITH SplitSting AS
           (SELECT
                LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1) AS Part
                    ,RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)) AS Remainder
                WHERE @String IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)-1)
                    ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder))
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                Remainder,null
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)=0
           )
           SELECT Part FROM SplitSting
       )
```