# How to retrieve commas delimited values in SQL to a ListBox separately

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008, where for each value id, I have inserted a list of values with comma delimited.

So In the front end, when I select a particular id from the `DropDownList`, I want to retieve the comma delimited values separately into to a `ListBox`.

Hope my question is clear. Kindly help...

Comment: in which SQL Server? (2005 or 2008 or 2012?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
 //doing this in front end - C#
 string values = getValuesFromDB(dropdownList.SelectedValue);
 myListBox.DataSource = values.Split(',');
 myListBox.DataBind();
```

OR

```
 foreach(string s in values.Split(','))
 {
   myListBox.Items.Add(s);
 }
```

There are also answers on SO that shows how to [convert CSV to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12129520/how-to-run-sql-server-stored-procedure-query-for-each-value-of-a-csv/12129695#12129695) and am sorry for not asking which SQL database you are using

UPDATE

```
private string getValuesFromDB(string selectedID)
{
    //this might not be the rea; query
    string query = "SELECT commaValues FROM myTable WHERE id = " + selectedID; 
    ....
    ....
    string commaSeparatedValues = "retrieved values from this recod";
    return commaSeparatedValues;
}
```

Comment: What would the getValuesFromDB(); be...??

Comment: how were you getting values from the DB? I expect you to implement that method providing the data access e.g. `select values from myTable where id=123`

Answer (score 0):

using string split function will give you values in array which you can loop through to assign in list box

pseudo code

```
string myids = //data retrived from DB
string [] id = myids.split(',') //I assume , as delimiter
//loop thorugh id array and assign it to listbox item.
for(int i=0; i<id.Length; i++)
{
listbox1.items.add(id[i]); //Assuming listbox1 is your Listbox control
}
```

there could be syntax errors but i think you got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the example Once data comes in to table then you can easily bind data in to list box.

**STEP 1**

Execute the following procedure in your Sql Server window.

The fn_CommaSeparatedStringToTable function accepts comma separated string and a value('Y' or 'N') to include NULL and EMPTY strings in the result set

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_CommaSeparatedStringToTable]
(
 @CommaSeparatedValues     VARCHAR(MAX),
 @IncludeEmptyStrings    CHAR(1)
)
RETURNS @Item TABLE 
(
   RowId int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL, 
   Value VARCHAR(200)
)
 AS
  BEGIN

      DECLARE @IndefOfComma int,
     @Value VARCHAR(200),@StartPos bigint,@EndPos 

      bigint,@LengthOfString int, @ReachedEnd Char(1)

  SET @StartPos=1
  SET @EndPos=0
  SET @LengthOfString=LEN(@CommaSeparatedValues)
  SET @ReachedEnd='N'

  WHILE @ReachedEnd<>'Y'
        BEGIN
              SET @EndPos=CHARINDEX(',',@CommaSeparatedValues,@StartPos)
              IF @EndPos>0
              BEGIN
                  SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@CommaSeparatedValues, @StartPos,@EndPos-  
 @StartPos) 
                  SET @StartPos=@EndPos+1      
              END
              ELSE
              BEGIN
                 SEt @ReachedEnd='Y'
                 SET @Value = SUBSTRING(@CommaSeparatedValues,   
 @StartPos,@LengthOfString-(@StartPos-1))
              END
              IF(@Value<>'' OR @IncludeEmptyStrings='Y')
              INSERT INTO @Item(Value) VALUES(@Value)
  END
  RETURN
 END
```

**STEP 2**

To access the function, use the following query

```
  Include Empty or Null String in the result

  SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_CommaSeparatedStringToTable]
  ('ALICE,BRAD,JOHN,JOE,MIC,SCAIF,JEMY, ,','Y')


 Do not include Empty or Null String in the result 
SELECT * FROM [dbo].[fn_CommaSeparatedStringToTable]
('ALICE,BRAD,JOHN,JOE,MIC,SCAIF,JEMY, ,','N')
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing the values on this way in the database not a good idea, because:

1: If you want to fill a dropdownlist may you will find the point when you need different id's, like:

```
1 - First Otion
3 - Second Option
11 - Third Option
```

Then it is hard to decode just from the values.

2: It always make it much longer to parse them. The storage is not so "expensive", then the processor time, so it is definietly not a good strategy.

However, if you would like to change it or solve it on an SQL level, you can write an SQL Function to parse the delimited string.

An SQL function what is doing something like this, can help:

```
DECLARE @string varchar(500)

--Here comes the selected one
SELECT @string = Value FROM List WHERE ID = 2

DECLARE @pos int
DECLARE  @id int
DECLARE @piece varchar(500)

DECLARE @returnTable table(
ID int,
Value varchar(64)
)

SET @id = 0

IF right(rtrim(@string),1) <> ','
 SET @string = @string  + ','

SET @pos =  patindex('%,%' , @string)
WHILE @pos <> 0 
BEGIN
 SET @piece = left(@string, @pos - 1)

 INSERT INTO @returnTable VALUES(@id, @piece)

 SET @id = @id + 1

 SET @string = stuff(@string, 1, @pos, '')
 SET @pos =  patindex('%,%' , @string)
END

SELECT * FROM @returnTable
```