# How to retrieve a sub string from from a column in SQL database into a ListBox

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

Kindly help me with the following :

I am using `SQL database server 2008`, in which I have a table with columns as shown in the image attached. [image: I want to retrieve the ToolTip column and extract string after **Controls:** and separate type=value strings and list in a <code>ListBox</code> separately]

I want to retrieve the ToolTip column and extract string after **Controls:** and separate type=value strings and list in a `ListBox` separately.

Then I want to loop through each row get the list and  compare this list with another set of similar list and check if they have same string lists. I haven't tried any code, since I don't know how to start in the first place. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: when you say "I haven't tried any code...", did you inherit this problem or you created it for yourself. Is there any reason why Tool_Tip cannot be a MULTILINE text instead of separating them with semicolon

Comment: Yea this this ToolTip table I am using for other purpose also too. I also wonder when I am saving this tooltip table, its was MULTILINE text. But in database it is stored as single line.

Comment: Have you tried to read it back and display it? It should preserve the newlines

Comment: Yes, I have used this to display as tooltip for `GridView` headers, it preserves the newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if you had

**Profile_Controls** Table

```
Profile_Name       Controls_Key     Controls_Value
-----------------------------------------------------
Lamp_Profile1      ON_OFF           ON
Lamp_Profile1      BRIGHTNESS       NONE
Fan_Profile1       ON_OFF           ON
Fan_Profile1       SPEED            NONE
.....
```

Then you can select

```
Select Controls_Key+'='+Controls_Value AS Settings From Profile_Controls Where Profile_Name = 'Fan_Profile1'

Results
-----------------
Settings
---------------------
ON_OFF=ON
SPEED=ON
```

This give you more flexibility as you can filter, JOIN, COMPARE, and use other built-in SQL functionality

If you still want to maintain your table structure like you have it

```
string[] mysplit = Tool_Tip.Split(s.Split(new string[]{"Controls:"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

string controls = mysplit[1].Substring(0); //ON_OFF=On;BRIGHTNESS=NONE

string[] eachSettings = controls.Split(';');

//eachSettings[0] = ON_OFF=ON
//eachSettings[1] = BRIGHTNESS=NONE
```

UPDATE

```
public System.Data.DataTable GetProfileSettings(string profilename)
{
   string sql = "Select Controls_Key+'='+Controls_Value AS Settings From Profile_Controls Where Profile_Name = '"+profilename+"'";
   //write ADO.Net code here to get settings into DataTable
   //DataTable dt = blah blah blah;

   return dt;
}
```

in your page

```
protected void SomeEvent_Handler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   myListBox2.DataSource = GetProfileSettings("FanProfile1");
   myListBox2.DataTextField = "Settings";
   myListBox2.DataBind();
}
```

You can use this link as reference for adding item to your listBox [How to retrieve commas delimited values in SQL to a ListBox separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312842/how-to-retrieve-commas-delimited-values-in-sql-to-a-listbox-separately/12312901#12312901)

Comment: You have given me a brilliant idea..Indeed I will follow your first idea. Just tell me how to use that Settings and put in a `ListBox` and loop to each row do the same and compare with my own `ListBox` with similar set of value.

Answer (score 0):

[String.Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) and more reading on [SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and SqlCommand

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about we fire a query like this

```
select tooltip from FooTable where Profile_Type='Foo_Profile_Type' and Profile_Name = 'Foo_Profile_Name'
```

and get

```
"Type = LAMP;Profile = Lamp_Profile1;Controls:ON_OFF = ON;BRIGHTNESS = NONE;"
```

Then

```
string str = returnedstring.Split(new string[]{"Controls:"})[2];
```

will give you

```
"Controls:ON_OFF = ON"
```

Comment: I would try this, but I want ON_OFF = ON and BRIGHTNESS = NONE in the `ListBox` and compare with another list and jump to the next row and again list similarly and compare with the same list.