# Trouble with SQL join

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Ok so I have some data in a product table that contains a category id column that only contains 2 of the 4 available characters used in the category list table.

Example: product  has category ID 'AA' but could be from either the Desktops (AAA) or Server (AAB) categories.

In the category table we have 3 columns that contain info to help us: include, atrID and valID. The valID column contains a comma-separated list of values (e.g. 'K01819' or 'K00846,K00851') that may contain only one ID or more. The atrID column contains a similar string (e.g. 'A00432'). The include column is either 1 or 0 based on some work done by a programmer that came and went long ago.

Basically he had trawled through the various tables and found that for certain categories (e.g. AA) we could join another table from the category table and use the atrID and list of valIDs to tie it all in.

Example:

Product "a" has a catID of AA and is a desktop machine. This belongs in category 'AAA' which has 0 for include, 'A00432' for atrID and 'K01819' for valID.

Example SQL to get category info:

```
SELECT cat.atrID, cat.valID, cat.[include]
FROM db.dbo.cat AS cat
WHERE cat.catID = 'AAA'
```

I would then save these variables in the .Net code and build the SQL depending on the value of include. I would also split the valID up and pass this in as individual parameters resulting in the following code being executed on the SQL server.

```
SELECT DISTINCT prod.prodID
FROM db.dbo.prod AS prod
INNER JOIN db.dbo.atr AS atr ON atr.prodID = prod.prodID
WHERE prod.catID = 'AA'
AND atr.atrID = 'A00432'
AND atr.valID NOT IN('K01819')
```

To change this for servers I would change the `NOT IN` to an `IN` as servers (AAB) have an include value of 1. Example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT prod.prodID
FROM db.dbo.prod AS prod
INNER JOIN db.dbo.atr AS atr ON atr.prodID = prod.prodID
WHERE prod.catID = 'AA'
AND atr.atrID = 'A00432'
AND atr.valID IN('K01819')
```

I use `IN` and `NOT IN` because some of the categories have more than one value in the valID column.

My question is, if I want to get the category for a specific product without previously knowing it, is it even possible? (Failing getting a list of all the products from the categories you think it's in and matching it in one or another of the lists). I've been telling my boss I can't figure it out for days now and I'm not getting anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

What I'm trying to do is get the category for any product. I included the above SQL as an example of how I get a list of products for the Desktop and Server categories.

I want the reverse, i.e. getting the 3 letter category from the categories table when I only have the two letter category from the product table.

EDIT 2:

Product table columns:
prodID varchar(40)
catID char(2)

Sample rows:
'S101010', 'AA' (desktop)
'S202020', 'AA' (server)
'S303030', 'ED' (laser printer)
'S404040', 'ED' (inkjet printer)

Category table columns:
catID varchar(4)
description varchar(50)
include bit (actually a tinyint which should go to show what I deal with on a daily basis =P)
atrID varchar(6)
valID varchar(250)

Sample rows:
'AAA', 'Desktops', 0, 'A00432', 'K01819'
'AAB', 'Servers', 1, 'A00432', 'K01819'
'EDA', 'Laser Printers', 1, 'A00172', 'K00846,K00851'
'EDB', 'Inkjet Printers', 1, 'A00172', 'K00845'

Attribute table columns:
prodID varchar(40)
catID char(2)
atrID varchar(10)
valID varchar(10)

Sample rows:
'S101010', 'AA', 'A00432', 'K01817'
'S202020', 'AA', 'A00432', 'K01819'
'S303030', 'ED', 'A00172', 'K00846'
'S303030', 'ED', 'A00172', 'K00851'
'S404040', 'ED', 'A00172', 'K00845'

What I have included above is how I get a list of products when I know category.catID. What I want is to be able to get the category when I only have product.prodID and product.catID.

I'm after something like this but it's incomplete and won't work as it is. I would then check the result of catIn.catID and catNotIn.catID to see which one wasn't null and that would be my category but I can't figure out the joins. If it is even possible. And it doesn't take into account the categories that have more than two variants.

```
SELECT prod.prodID, catIn.catID, catNotIn.catID
FROM product AS prod
INNER JOIN attributes AS atr ON atr.prodID = prod.prodID
LEFT OUTER JOIN category AS catIn ON LEFT(catIn.catID, 2) = prod.catID AND catIn.atrID = atr.atrID --more conditions needed here
LEFT OUTER JOIN category AS catNotIn ON LEFT(catNotIn.catID, 2) = prod.catID AND catIn.atrID = atr.atrID --more conditions needed here
```

I hope this explains what I'm after a bit better.

Comment: It's an incredible challenge to automate the cleaning of bad data. You have to have some information in your products table that can be matched to the categories table. The prod.catID was SUPPOSED to be that. If you cannot match like that, you'll have to create a screen that shows the user all the possible matches (JOIN prod catID AA ON catID LIKE 'AA%') and give them the option to choose which is right.  Make it as easy as possible, but make the user(s) clean up their own bad data.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option. I'm having to join this because we're implementing a new system to adjust prices based on different customers at the mercy of their account managers. I need to figure the category out because they may specify a markup for the category but not the individual product, and I need to make sure the price matches up to what the account manager expects when the custoemr is browsing products. It wouldn't be such a problem if it was just the obscure less-used categories but as it's desktops and servers I'm in a bit of a pickle.

Comment: customer specific markups should be stored in a separate table.  you definitely need to adjust your data model.  products --> product_categories (for types of products), customers --> customer_categories (for types of customers). Then you'd need to map product_categories to customer_categories so your AMs can set mark-ups for a customer group by product or by product category... or set mark-ups for a specific customer by product or by product category.  I'm assuming you db.dbo.cat is for product categories.

Comment: I'm not doing very well at this am I.... We have a table with products in. We also have a table with categories in that largely only contain the 2-letter category but have up to 4 letters. Therein lies the problem in figuring out which category a product belongs to if you only have the product info available to you. Our markups are indeed stored in a different table. The database isn't **-that-** badly organised but it certainly couldn't be considered well organised.

Comment: am I right in thinking there once was (or perhaps still is) a category id of 'AA' out there for computers and they have since branched out to 'AAA', desktops and 'AAB' servers?  It sounds like it might be the other way in your question... That AAA and AAB could both be parents and AA might be a child of either.  I don't mean to ridicule the db's design, I just think there might be a better way.  Is there a recursive relationship on the cat table?  like a parent ID that references the next category up in the hierarchy of categories?

Comment: The product table still only contains AA as it's catID column is a varchar(2). The categories tables was built later on to separate Desktops (AAA) and Servers (AAB) based on the attribute values in the atr table. The problem is that if you only have the product ID and need to find if it belongs to AAA or AAB it looks to be impossible.

Comment: It possibly is.  Your first order of business is to expand the products table catID to match the cat table's catID.  Where are are the attributes for each product stored?  It's fine to have data in categories to know what attributes are available for a product category, but each product has its own value(s) of those attribute options, no?

Comment: The problem is that this products table gets overridden every day from the product feed coming in from CNet. They only provide the 2-letter category. I'm not even sure what the attributes table contains, but I do know that for a certain atrID, one of the valID is there for servers and not for desktops. I've spent two weeks working on this system so and I still don't fully understand the relationships in the database and there's no documentation.

Comment: That changes a lot!  You have a way of determining whether catID "AA" is a server or a desktop once you find the one atrID specific to servers and query on it.  Do you need help with querying on it or finding the one atrID?

Comment: Yeah i can't see it.. I know that if i have the 3 letter catID i can join on the atrID and find a list of products but i couldn't find a way to do it if i just had prod.ProdID. It needs to take into account the include bit and look for the presence or absence of the corresponding valIDs. Maybe ive been looking at it for too long >_<

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start by saying your data model is pretty bad.  You shouldn't have a comma-list of values where you need to then split and match against.  It should be a table relationship.  But I digress...

So if the only difference is whether or not you use `IN` vs `NOT IN` based on the value of `include` then if I were to write this wholly on the server I would do this:

First, get yourself a nice CSV split UDF.  [how to split and insert CSV data into a new table in single statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265316/how-to-split-and-insert-csv-data-into-a-new-table-in-single-statement)  This is a good example -- nice and simple.

Then, the query (which I would turn into a stored procedure) would likely look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SprocNameHere
@prodID INT
AS

-- I'm making assumptions about the data types here.  Fix them accordingly
DECLARE @atrID INT
DECLARE @valID varchar(MAX)
DECLARE @include BIT
DECLARE @catID varchar(50)

-- given the passed in product ID, look up @catID
SELECT @catID = catID FROM prod WHERE prodID = @prodID

SELECT @atrID = cat.atrID, @valID = cat.valID, @include = cat.[include]
FROM db.dbo.cat AS cat
WHERE cat.catID = @catID


SELECT DISTINCT prod.prodID
FROM db.dbo.prod AS prod
INNER JOIN db.dbo.atr AS atr ON atr.prodID = prod.prodID
LEFT JOIN dbo.inline_split_me(',', @valID) ism ON ism.Value = atr.valID
WHERE prod.catID = 'AA' -- is this hardcoded or should this come from the query above??  How do you convertt 'AAA' to 'AA'?  What Table/relationship/concept does this?
AND atr.atrID = @atrID
AND ((@include = 0 AND ism.Value IS NULL) OR (@include = 1 AND ism.Value IS NOT NULL))
```

Very hard to make sure my syntax above is accurate as I don't have a full working model.  But here's the general idea: Your UDF `inline_split_me` splits records into a "table" which you can then join against.  By using LEFT JOIN, if there's not a  match between the `atr` table, then ism.Value will be null.  This can be used to do `NOT IN`.  The opposite is, then, also true for the `IN` simulation.

EDIT 1:  Based on your feedback, Here's a test bed I came up with.  I don't have a complete view of the data, but I think this is what you are looking for (or at least getting close).  Comment and I'll adjust.

Given your sample data, I ran this in my tempdb.  Since I didn't have an Attribute record for EDB I can't be certain if I'm getting back what I'm supposed to get back.  I also get back two records S303030, one for each of the valIDs in the Attribute table.  You can use DISTINCT to get back just one if you're looking only for uniqueness across ProdID + Category.CatID, or if there's a piece of the puzzle I didn't understand, let me know and I'll tweak my answer.  This works for everything except Ink Jets, because your sample data didn't have an inkjet record in the #Category table.  If I fake one with say `UNION SELECT 'S404040', 'ED', 'A00172', 'K00845'` then it seems to work.

```
--DROP TABLE #Product
--DROP TABLE #Category
--DROP TABLE #Attribute

--DROP FUNCTION inline_split_me

GO
CREATE FUNCTION inline_split_me (@SplitOn char(1),@String nvarchar(max))
RETURNS @results TABLE(Part NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN

    IF (CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1<= 0)
        INSERT INTO @results
        SELECT @string AS Part
    ELSE
        WITH SplitSting AS
            (
            SELECT
                LEFT(@String,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1) AS Part
                    , CASE WHEN LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String) > 0 THEN RIGHT(@String,LEN(@String)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)) ELSE NULL END AS Remainder
                WHERE @String IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,@String)-1>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                LEFT(Remainder,CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)-1)
                    ,RIGHT(Remainder,LEN(Remainder)-CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder))
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)-1>0
            UNION ALL
            SELECT
                Remainder,null
                FROM SplitSting
                WHERE Remainder IS NOT NULL AND CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,Remainder)=0
            )
            INSERT INTO @results
            SELECT Part FROM SplitSting

RETURN
END

GO


CREATE TABLE #Product
(
    prodID varchar(40)
    , catID char(2)
)

CREATE TABLE #Category
(
    catID varchar(4)
    , description varchar(50)
    , include bit --(actually a tinyint which should go to show what I deal with on a daily basis =P)
    , atrID varchar(6)
    , valID varchar(250)
)

CREATE TABLE #Attribute
(
    prodID varchar(40)
    , catID char(2)
    , atrID varchar(10)
    , valID varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO #Product
SELECT 'S101010', 'AA'
UNION SELECT 'S202020', 'AA'
UNION SELECT 'S303030', 'ED'
UNION SELECT 'S404040', 'ED'

INSERT INTO #Category
SELECT 'AAA', 'Desktops', 0, 'A00432', 'K01819'
UNION SELECT 'AAB', 'Servers', 1, 'A00432', 'K01819'
UNION SELECT 'EDA', 'Laser Printers', 1, 'A00172', 'K00846,K00851'
UNION SELECT 'EDB', 'Inkjet Printers', 1, 'A00172', 'K00845'

INSERT INTO #Attribute
SELECT 'S101010', 'AA', 'A00432', 'K01817'
UNION SELECT 'S202020', 'AA', 'A00432', 'K01819'
UNION SELECT 'S303030', 'ED', 'A00172', 'K00846'
UNION SELECT 'S303030', 'ED', 'A00172', 'K00851'

-- make sure it works with just one parameter
SELECT * FROM dbo.inline_split_me(',', 'K00846')

-- so you can see the split
SELECT * FROM dbo.inline_split_me(',', 'K00846,K00851')

-- so you can see the split in reference to the category
SELECT c.*, Part
FROM #Category c
OUTER  APPLY dbo.inline_split_me(',', c.valID) split

SELECT p.*, a.*, c.*
FROM #Product p
INNER JOIN #Attribute a ON a.prodID = p.prodID AND a.catID = p.catID
INNER JOIN #Category c ON c.atrID = a.atrID
    AND (
            (c.include = 0 AND a.valID NOT IN (SELECT Part FROM dbo.inline_split_me(',', c.valID)))
            OR (c.include = 1 AND a.valID IN (SELECT Part FROM dbo.inline_split_me(',', c.valID)))
        )
ORDER BY a.ProdID, a.atrID--, c.catID

DROP TABLE #Product
DROP TABLE #Category
DROP TABLE #Attribute

DROP FUNCTION inline_split_me
```

Comment: Sorry I probably wasn't clear enough. I don't have the category at hand when trying to get the data for a specific product. I included the SQL that I use to get a list of products to see if it could be reversed to be used to get the category for any product.

Comment: I changed my response slightly based on your comments.  I still have a question on how we get from 'AAA' to 'AA'.  If you can resolve that, does this solution make sense to you?

Comment: Yeah the data is pretty bad but there's nothing I can do about it, it's a feed from CNet. The categories were defined ages ago and since then everyone has been used to having separate listings for AAA and AAB. The other system works because it loops through the categories to get any markups applied and saves the prices out to a different table. It always knows which category they belong to. Unfortunately I've been told doing it the same way is not an option because there is the potential for the account managers to add markups for every product on every client.

Comment: To get from AAA to AA I was just doing LEFT(cat.catID, 2). This is where my problem lies. Prod.catID is a varchar(2) and cat.catID is a varchar(4). I want to get the category, not the product. I already have the product but need the category to apply the markups (which are in yet another table but that's not a problem if I can figure this out). I'm convinced it's impossible but I'm not exactly an expert so I put the question out on here. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: What would be helpful would be a small table definition of the tables in play with a sample record or two of each, and then a simple walkthrough of how you want to get from Point A (what you know) to Point Z (where you want to go) and what hops you're taking in between.  Everytime I think I understand what you're trying to do, I find out I don't :)  If you can edit your original post to include the info you just gave me here, as well as some of the info I'm asking for, I (or someone else here) should be able to help. If you can do it manually with code logic, there's prolly a SQL solution

Comment: There, done =] and the thing is I can't figure out how to do it in code because I don't think it's possible. But like I said I'm no expert and was wondering if I'm missing something.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to add sample rows... It's Friday afternoon and my head is fried. Thanks a lot for your help so far. Hope that clears up a few questions.

Comment: Big edits.  Please check my EDIT code and give it a shot.  I had to tweak the inline_split_me that I previously recommended as it didn't work when there was only one item in the list.  My example code is a full solution that you can test with.

Comment: I'll give it a shot tomorrow, just got home and gotta connect in to work. I'm not so sure though as c.catID is up to 4 characters and p.catID and a.catID are only two letters. Thanks though I'll give it a shot =]

Comment: If you'll notice I'm not using any of the catID's for anything except output, so you should be fine.  Please try it and let me know where it falls short.  Add to the context if my solution needs refining.

Comment: Yeah sorry I noticed that immediately this morning. Friday night is not a good time to be making comments on code solutions. I need to get the other database changed to compat mode 90 or above before I can test, it's still at 80 =\