# SQL Query with duplication and editing

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, sql-server-2012

I am new to SQL and have a question that I have not been able to find the answer to yet, probably because I am not sure exactly what to search for. I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a DB that was converted from an old Access DB (Jobs DB) and need to join that with a SQL Spatial DB. The join would be most likely a ONE to MANY as there is one "LOT" in the spatial DB and would correspond to many possible "JOBS" in the Jobs DB. The join would have to be on the "LOT" except the only problem is that the field that would contain the "LOT" in the Jobs DB is text and might contain multiple lots in the same field, example below.

"L.0005&L.0006" in the Jobs DB would correspond to "5" & "6" (separate rows) in the Spatial DB

What I need is to create another row and copy in all the columns but modify the first to be just "5" instead of "L.0005" and the new row be "6" instead of L.0006". The key would then have to move from just the "JOB_NUMBER" to "JOB_NUMBER" & "LOT" for that table. If I could do this in all one query, that would be great, but if it needs to be 2 queries, then I can do the join to the Spatial DB myself I think, it's just the first part that has me stumped.

If anyone knows of a better way to accomplish this, I am open to suggestions for sure. If this has already been answered elsewhere, please direct me to that solution as, like I said above, I don't think I even know what to search for specifically and haven't found anything with what I am searching.

Comment: this question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265316/how-to-split-and-insert-csv-data-into-a-new-table-in-single-statement

Comment: It looks promising. I will dive into it and see if I can get it to works. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: What is the status on this question? If solved please update. If not solved, I could have an answer for you, provided you can tell whether or not the Jobs DB always will have the lot info structured as [L.????[&[L.????[…]]].